# Remove the last comma from array

Tags: arrays, powershell

Created the following code below, however, I am getting a comma on the last string in the array that I would like to remove.  How do I either change the way I am adding the comma to the array or simply remove the last comma from the array?

```
clear
$dataOut = ''
$excludeList = 'choco*','kb*','dotnet*','netfx*','*.install*','*.portable*','vcredist*','packages*','lessmsi*'
$appsInstalled = Get-ChildItem -Exclude $excludeList -Recurse -Path "C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\*.nuspec"

Foreach ($app in $appsInstalled) {
[xml]$XmlDocument = Get-Content $app.Fullname
#$appsInstalled = "$($XmlDocument.package.metadata.Title) v$($XmlDocument.package.metadata.Version)" + ", "
$appsInstalled = $XmlDocument.package.metadata.Title + " v" +$XmlDocument.package.metadata.Version + ", "
$dataOut = $dataOut + $appsInstalled
}
$dataOut
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are after is called *trimming*. There are three cases, trimming from left, right and both ends. That is, removing leading extra characters, trailing ones and from both directions.

The `$dataOut` is not an array but a string. One can use .Net's String class' [.Trim()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trim?view=net-7.0) method. It will remove leading and trailing characters Like so,

```
$s = "foo,bar,zof, "
# Print trimmed string, pipes will show that space was removed too
"|{0}|" -f $s.trim(@(',', ' '))
|foo,bar,zof|
```